# Having issues with colors not being defined

Tags: flutter, dart

having issues with colors it's saying "the named parameter 'colors' isn't defined"

```
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: const [
                                    Color(0xffec2F4B),
                                    Color(0xffC02425)
                                  ],
```

Comment: can you post full code?

Comment: full code https://pastebin.com/fsWanXYb

Comment: try type 'flutter clean'  in the terminal then compile again...

Comment: error is still there

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9tcDQjKt  I tried your code and its worked.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working its weird in the sense all the imports are valid and it should run but in vscode its marked as an error

Comment: try to run 'flutter doctor' in the terminal and see how..

Comment: this is what hoving over it gives me:
"The named parameter 'colors' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'colors'.dartundefined_named_parameter"

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of this error?

Comment: https://imgflip.com/gif/4h5re5

Comment: I assume you have, but have you had a look at this - as it seems to be the same issue. What version of flutter are you on? [github link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63908)

Comment: after checking the version is 1.22.0, although I'm not sure and I can't explain it but after a restart, my computer for windows update the error was gone.